# pandas time series boxplot

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13gT8-WfeSHfo71nL9BOPk1XA3fDZhNtG/view?usp=sharing). 
You can take a look the data in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPm7q.png) in as an image. I need to create a time series box plot. However, when I use the following code

```
df.boxplot(showfliers=False)
```

I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjVjl.png) box plot where each dates data are equally spaced in X-axis. No matter what time differences between one data point to another - the space between one box plot to another is constant.

For example, I have August 29 and August 31 data where they supposed to be close to each other. On the other hand, the space between July 7 and July 24 supposed to be much more. In both cases, they have the same space between them.

The whole code is provided below -

```
    #list of path of multiple images
    images = ["D:/20180615.tif", "D:/20180629.tif", "D:/20180707.tif",....]
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    for i in images:
        #converiting images in np array and taking care of no data value
        array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(i,nodata_to_value=9999)
        xarray =array.flatten()
        index = np.argwhere(xarray==9999)
        x = np.delete(xarray, index)

        #naming the column after the date
        date_name = i[3:7]+"/"+i[7:9]+"/"+i[9:11]
        date = datetime.strptime(date_name , '%Y/%m/%d').date()

        #append the data to the panda series
        df[date] = pd.Series(y)

   #creating the box plot
   df.boxplot(showfliers=False)
```

Is there any way to take care of the box plot placement according to the dates of the data?

Comment: You can try setting the `xticks` values and labels to the full time series, then it should plot only on the days when there are values